# Liquibase: How do I export changes since the last import?

Tags: database, liquibase

I'm using Liquibase 2.0.5.  I have the following process:

1. Export Liquibase changes to an XML file.
2. Log in to database and run some db command (e.g. `ALTER TABLE ...`)
3. Export the change made in step 2 as a Liquibase changeset.

My question is, how do I do step 3?  I use the following script to do step 1 ...

```bash
/opt/liquibase/liquibase --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \
  --classpath=~/.m2/repository//mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.15/mysql-connector-java-5.1.15.jar \
  --changeLogFile=~/db.changelog.xml \
  --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db" \
  --username=user \
  --password=pass \
  generateChangeLog
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing "manual" `ALTER TABLE` statements at all. Once you use Liquibase ***all*** schema changes should go through it. Doing manual `ALTER` statements totally defeat Liquibase's purpose.

If you really, really can't avoid bypassing Liquibase, then use the `diff` or `diffChangeLog` commands to view the delta (http://www.liquibase.org/manual/command_line)

If you find yourself doing that on a regular basis, you should re-think why and how you use Liqubiase.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying.  Let's say my schema and table structures are already in place and I want to add a new column to a table.  Given that I'm using Liquibase, what's the right way to do that, if running an SQL "ALTER TABLE" statement is off the table.

Comment: To add a new column, you create a new changeSet (in your change log) with an `addColumn` command. Liquibase is a tool to manage ***and*** apply your schema migrations. Please read the tutorial and the manual.